# What are some solutions to getting the money back with the Parity bug?

Tags: parity, bug

Having over $150+ Million stuck in parity. What are some proposed solutions to unfreeze these funds?

Comment: When you say 'stuck in parity' do you mean 'stuck in a parity multisig wallet contract'. If so please edit your question. I don't think there is a way to get Ether stuck in parity itself.

Answer (score 2):

The only possible solution is a Hard Fork: https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/7bchez/parity_multisig_wallets_deployed_after_730_issue/dph08e9/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.